# Node.js: Inserting a line after a particular line in a text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to build a command line application, so that to block an ip (or whatever) I need not to update the conf file. For this, I need to insert a particular line of code with the ip at a particular place in the conf file. I know the CLI part. Can anybody help me with the inserting part?
I wrote the code as follows, but is writing some gibberish!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var cli = require('cli');
var fs = require('fs');
cli.parse({
    block:   ['b', 'Block the ip:port'],
    ip: ['i', 'provide ip address', 'string', ''],
    port: ['p', 'provide port number', 'int', 0],
});

cli.main(function(args, options)
{
    if(options.block)
    {
       fs.readFile('nginx.conf', function(err, data) {
          if(err) throw err;
          data = data.toString();
          var array = data.toString().split("\r\n");

          array[4] ='deny ' + cli.getValue(options.ip) + ':' + cli.getValue(options.port);
          for(i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
            fs.writeFile('nginx1.conf', array[i]+'\r\n', function () {})
          };
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Callback in for loop is not a good idea. Try this code -

```
fs.readFile('nginx.conf', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
  //data = data.toString();
  var array = data.toString().split("\n");

  array[4] ='deny '+cli.getValue(options.ip)+':'+cli.getValue(options.port);
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    fs.appendFileSync('nginx1.conf', array[i]+'\n');
  }
});
```